# Add status icon to image in CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have a CListCtrl in MFC where I am appending a set of 128x128 pixel images. Now I would like to append a 16x16 small status icon (OK/NOK style) to those images. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you give a small example (picture or explain more) where you want to append them ?

Comment: [Image Overlays in ImageLists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az91ees4.aspx) on MSDN seems to be what you need to investigate. (Deleted my answer.)

Comment: @acraig5075 hey I cannot find any good example on this nor any documentation at all and therefore I am stuck. Can you give any guidance? (MSDN example is not enough for me at least)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may not solve your problem, but is near to be a solution.

```
CBitmap drawBitmap;

HICON hicon= m_pImageList->ExtractIcon(ix);
drawBitmap.Attach(hicon);

CDC dc;
dc.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
dc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);


CPoint pt;
// do your calculations: pt will be define in what part of the image the icon will appear 
DrawIcon(&dc.GetSafeHdc(), pt.x, pt.y, IDI_YOUR_ICON);
DeleteDC(dc);

m_pImageList->Replace(ix, &drawBitmap, (CBitmap*)NULL);
```

ix is the index of the one you want to replace.

Comment: I can say I already used an approach like this on a real application.

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting previous answer, I discovered that it exists [CImageList::SetOverlayImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a88tw0wh.aspx)

Comment: Than you. But I can't find any good example or even any good documentation on how to do this and therefore I am stuck.